# How can an assignment be used as an operand to the != operator?

Tags: c

For example:

```
while((*s1++=*s2++)! ='\0')
```

How can the assignment of `*s2++` to `*s1++` be compared with `'\0'`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the result of an assignment expression in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567622/what-is-the-result-of-an-assignment-expression-in-c)

Comment: How would I know that this is a duplicate question

Comment: By searching before you asked, and reading the search results.  For example, if you had searched for "[c] assignment expression" you would have found the Q&A that I found.

Answer (score 1):

The value of an assignment expression is the value that was assigned to the left operand of the expression.

So what you have there is a test that the value assigned to `*s1` is not equal to `'\0'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering

Comment: How would I come to know that this is a duplicate question