# C assignment expression in argument to sizeof

Tags: c, variable-assignment

According to this question "[What does an assignment return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514569/what-does-an-assignment-return)" and 
[What is the result of an assignment expression in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567622/what-is-the-result-of-an-assignment-expression-in-c)

[Sandro Munda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9514608/3094631) and [Ahmed Salah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42340709/3094631) write

> 1. Assign the value 2 to i
> 2. Evaluate the i variable and display it

So, based on the statement above, I expect the following code will output

```
1
1
1
```

However, it outputs

```
1
0
1
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void func(int a){}
int main()
{
    int var;
    //////////////////////
    var=0;
    func(var=1);
    printf("%d\n",var);
    /////////////////////
    var=0;
    sizeof(var=1);
    printf("%d\n",var);
    /////////////////////
    var=0;
    printf("",var=1);
    printf("%d\n",var);

   return 0;
}
```

My question is what makes this difference?
Why does assignment in "sizeof()" not work as two other counterpart?

Comment: This is a dupe afaik. Long story short, because `sizeof` is special.

Comment: ["_When applied to an expression, sizeof does not evaluate the expression,..._"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof)