# Writing replacement for strcpy

Tags: c, strcpy

I have to write a replacement for strcpy without using pointers or the function having a return value...
How could this be done?!

this is what i have so far but it uses return values.

```
void str_copy(char destination [], char source []) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; source[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        destination[i] = source[i];
    destination[i] = '\0';
    return destination;
}
```

Comment: without using pointers? Not possible. In your example, `destination` and `source` are adjusted to pointers.

Comment: In C, arrays decays into pointers. See: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html

Comment: If is useful for you, you can use `memcpy(destination, source, strlen(source) * sizeof(char))`

Comment: One might note that `strcpy()` returns a `char *` with the target address. If you want a proper replacement, `void` is probably not the proper return type, while `return destination;` is actually fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suggest writing the function this way:

```
void str_copy( char destination [], const char source [] ) 
{
    for(size_t i=0; source[i]; i++ )  destination[i] = source[i];
    destination[i] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the return statement.

The function can look the following way

```
void str_copy( char destination [], const char source [] ) {
    size_t i = 0;
    while ( destination[i] = source[i] ) i++;
}
```

Comment: @iharob I think this requirement is understood incorrectly.

Comment: Minor: `int i` --> `size_t i`.

Comment: an assignment is always 'true', so this will result in a 'forever' loop

Comment: @user3629249 Are you sure that the assignment is always true?

Comment: @user3629249 Where did you get that? In C, an assignment [has the value of the left operand after the assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514569/what-does-an-assignment-return). The loop terminates *after* copying the final `\0`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to return *destination*?  Since you passed the address of the first element by using the empty brackets, the destination array should be changed without the return.