# C - Output explanation of printf("%d %d\n",k=1,k=3);

Tags: c, printf, variable-assignment, function-calls, sequence-points

How to explain the output of the below code:

```
include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int k;
    printf("%d %d\n",k=1,k=3);
    return 0;
}
```

[Ideone Link](http://ideone.com/6v8aNE)

My thinking was that `1` will be assigned to `k` variable and then `1` would be printed. Similarly `3` will be assigned to `k` and output will be `3`.

**Expected Output**

```
1 3
```

**Actual Output**

```
1 1
```

I am extrapolating from

```
int a;
if (a = 3) { 
    ...
}
```

is equal to

```
if (3) { 
    ... 
}
```

Please let me know where am I going wrong?

Comment: @CinCout Sorry, I Noticed It Later.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is, the order of evaluation of function arguments are not defined, and there's no sequence point between the evaluation or arguments. So, this statement

```
 printf("%d %d\n",k=1,k=3)
```

invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as you're trying to modify the same variable more than once without a sequence point in between.

Once a program invoking UB is run and (if) there's an output, it cannot be justified anyway, the output can be anything.

Comment: that is fine, one assignment, will print the value of `k`, i.e., 3.

Comment: I Think This Answer is wrong http://stackoverflow.com/a/9514591/5473170 . Can You Check It.

Comment: @SurajJain It's not a best one, but looks fine, in general. Why'd think it's incorrect?

Comment: It says rvalue getreturn, isn't it lvalue, i dont know subsequent answer say so

Comment: `rvalue` is not a standard C term, AFAIR. it's non-lvalue, or better, `value of an expression`.

Comment: you mean lvalue is not standard C term?

Comment: @SurajJain rvalue.

Comment: From C Standard Section 6.5.16 ' An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.
'

Comment: Now even if he writes expression evaluates to non-lvalue isn't it wrong?

Answer (score -4):

I expect the reason you're seeing `1 1` is because the two assignment statements are happening control is passed to `printf`.

```
printf("%d %d\n",k=1,k=3);
```

So in response to the down-votes, yes, this this is undefined behavior, and therefore you shouldn't count on this behavior continuing. However, in terms of identifying why the output was `1 1` and not `1 3`, we could infer that the assignment of `3` may have been stomped on by a subsequent assignment of `1`.

When printf is invoked, the call stack contains two entries containing the final value of `k`, which is `1`.

You can test this out by replacing those with a function that prints something when it executes.

Sample Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int test(int n) {
    printf("Test(%d)\n", n);
    return n;
}

int main(void) {
    int k;
    printf("%d %d\n",k=test(1), k=test(3));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Test(3)
Test(1)
1 1
```

Comment: This is a poor explanation at  a likely much more contrived reason

Comment: @q.Then Poor is a mild word, this is wrong.

Comment: I'm genuinely curious as to how my explanation is wrong. Is the argument just that multiple assignment is UB?

Comment: `I expect the reason you're seeing 1 1 is because`...there's no universal reason. so any one reason , mentioned is wrong. An answer, if any, will be very very platform and environment specific.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Yes, the behavior is undefined, but there's nothing wrong with speculating about what it does.

Comment: @KeithThompson Very correct sir, but the problem is, without an explicit mention to those aspects, someone without proper insights coming accross the answer will come up with a question like, why in my case it is "3  3"? The same as the one case printf evaluates arguments right to left and something....without specific context, that is not guaranteed, right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: The answer acknowledges that the behavior is undefined.

Comment: In all fairness, I don't think I explicitly mentioned UB in the initial answer. The intent was speculating on what the poster's compiler actually did, rather than what the language spec requires/allows, but I should have been more explicit.