# Why does an assignment works as a condition?

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements

I know that an assignment can be used as a condition in () after if statement. Like

```
int i;
if(i = 1) printf("Hey guys !");
```

.
But It is unlike usual conditions like `a < b` , so I can`t understand its mechanism. Why can it works as a condition?

Comment: It will evaluate to 1. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514569/what-does-an-assignment-return

Comment: The point you have to understand is that `if` isn't limited to just some "conditions", you can write in any kind of expression; after it is evaluated, it is converted to `bool` (if it isn't already) and, if the result is `true`, the body of the `if` is executed.