# Why assignment operator = doesn't return the value of pointer but the dereference value?

Tags: c++

From [What does an assignment return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514569/what-does-an-assignment-return) :

> An assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment

and this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int a[5] = { 0,1,2 };
    int* a_ptr = a;
    int b = (*a_ptr++ = 3); //int *b won't compile
    cout << b << endl; //3
}
```

What is the **left operand** of `=` when evaluating `(*a_ptr++ = 3)` ?

What's the definition of an **operand**?  In my mind, an operand is an identifier or name which is `aptr`.

Comment: An operand is whatever "argument" you give to the operator. Does not have to be an identifier or name - `3` is neither, but still you used it as an operand without issue.

Comment: Why did you tag this with C?  This is C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left operand is `*a_ptr++`. As per the [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), it's evaluated as

```
*(a_ptr++)
```

where the post-increment is sequenced as a side effect, after the execution of the statement. The value of the operand is the result of the statement. So, it's equivalent to

```
 int b = (*a_ptr = 3);
 a_ptr++;
```

That said, in general, Operands are expressions or values on which an operator operates or works. So, it can be

- a variable (ex: `var`, as in `int var`)
- a literal (`5` or '"Hello"')
- an expression (like `*a_ptr++`)

Answer (score 3):

`int b = (*a_ptr++ = 3);` is *grouped* as `int b = (*(a_ptr++) = 3);`. Note that the parentheses are superfluous; you could have written

```
int b = *a_ptr++ = 3;
```

which in many ways makes the result more obvious, since the *right-to-left associativity* of `=` is such that the 3 carries over to the value of `b`.

`a_ptr++` is an expression equal to `a_ptr` but it will point to the second element of the array `a` once the whole statement completes. Since you don't make use of that incremented pointer, the `++` is a red-herring, so the statement simplifies to

```
int b = *a_ptr = 3;
```

whereupon it's clear that `*a_ptr = 3` has the effect of setting the first element of the array `a` to 3 *and* is an expression equal to 3, which is assigned to `b`.

Comment: Would be better to mention operator precedence as well.

Comment: @Jarvis: Operator precedence drops out of the language grammer. It's not therefore a fundamental concept. I prefer to talk in terms of groupings. That said, feel free to put in an answer of your own.