# How is the assignment operator treated in the first expression of the ternary operator?

Tags: c, conditional-operator, assignment-operator

If I give an **Equal to** relational operator in the first expression of the ternary operator of the following code, then it outputs ***10,20***, which I have understood.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=10, c, b;
    
    c = (a==99) ? b = 11:20;
    
    printf("%d, %d", a, c);

    return 0;
}
```

But, When I place an **Assignment** operator instead of the **Equal to** relational operator (code is given below), then it outputs ***99, 11***. Now I am not getting how this **Assignment** operator is treated in the first expression of the ternary operator.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=10, c, b;
    
    c = (a=99) ? b = 11:20;
    
    printf("%d, %d", a, c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The assignment operator sets a to 99 and since 99 is a nonzero value, it is true. So c is set to 11.

Comment: As for the `b = 11` part, b is set to 11 and the value of b is "returned", so when the condition is true c is set to 11 too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does an assignment return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514569/what-does-an-assignment-return)

Comment: @PaulHankin Yes, I have got my answer. I will accept an answer.

Comment: Notably, it's considered very bad practice to mix `=` with other operators except when it's used for storing the final result. Having more than one assignment in the same expression is some major code stink. Both `=` and `?:` are dangerous operators that come with a lot of subtle special rules. Since there is no award for most operators in a single line, such lines should instead be broken up into several.

Comment: @Lundin You are correct, I don't want to make my code more complex. But this question came in an exam, so I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
c = (a==99) ? b = 11:20;
```

is doing the same as

```
if (a == 99)
{
    c = b = 11;
}
else
{
    c = 20;
}
```

Likewise this line

```
c = (a=99) ? b = 11:20;
```

is doing the same as

```
if (a = 99)
{
    c = b = 11;
}
else
{
    c = 20;
}
```

The interresting part is

```
if (a = 99)
{
    ...
```

which performs an assignment to `a` and then checks whether the assigned value is zero (false) or non-zero (true). So it can be written as:

```
a = 99;
if (a != 0)
{
    ...
```

BTW: `if (a != 0)` can also be written as `if (a)`

Comment: We can simply say that **a = 99** means **true** as a condition.

Comment: @RAWNAKYAZDANI Correct. Using `a = 0` as a condition will produce false while `a = non-zero-value` as a condition will produce true.

Answer (score 1):

`a=99` is an assignment to the variable `a` of the value `99`.  `99` is true in C, so the variables `c` and `b` are both assigned the value `11` in your 2nd program.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment operator sets variable a to 99 and any value greater than zero is true,So it returns True and sets variable c  to 11.