# Can someone explain to me why c=1?

Tags: c

I have been learning c recently and came across this problem. I understand that b=(a=10)=10 (correct me if my thought process is wrong please) but i can't understand why c=1, so it would be amazing if someone could explain it to me. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b=(a=10);
    int c=(a==10);
    printf("B %d\n",b);
    printf("C %d\n",c);
}
```

Comment: It's a comparison – comparisons *always* yield either 0 or 1, guaranteed by the standard, no matter if ==, !=, <, >, ...

Comment: Because `a==10` is a comparison and can be only true or false. Which have values `1` and `0` in C.

Comment: What did your C book say that `==` returns? That's where should be looking - this isn't an interactive beginner tutorial to replace conventional studies. If you don't understand what the book says, then by all means ask here with an example from the book.

Comment: I guess this was a question during exam. The == sign returns either 1 or 0. So at the beginning you set a=10 and then you are asking the computer IF a==10. Logically, the computer answers with 1 which means YES a is equal to 10

Answer (score 1):

You assign to `c` the result of expression `a == 10` which evaluates to either 1 if condition is true (`a` is equal to 10) or 0 if condition is false.

`a = 10` is an assignment operation while `a == 10` is a comparison.
Assignments [evaluate to the value of the left operand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9514595/5457426) after the assignment is done. In your case you assign a value of 10 to `a` and then the whole expression evaluates to the value of `a` afterwards , so 10.

Comparisons evaluate to either 1 or 0 based on whether the two operands are equal or not. In the case of `a == 10` they are equal, so the whole expression evaluates to 1.

Comment: FYI, expressions “yield”, “produce”, or “evaluate to” their results. Except for function calls, they do not “return” results, because there is (semantically, regardless of implementation) no call to a subroutine to return from.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that true or false would give an actual value to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

`a == 10` is a comparison which returns either `1` or `0`. As the value of `a` is 10, this comparison returns `1`which is assigned to `c`. Thus the value of `c` is `1`.